# Can't fully control settings in audio_services

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio, audio-service

I can't fully control settings in audio_services.

When I only have `MediaControl.pause`, it only displays the pause button. But as soon as I add `MediaControl.skipToPrevious` and `MediaControl.skipToNext` they appear regardless of `androidCompactActionIndices`. When adding additional buttons such as `MediaControl.stop` they do not appear.

This is my code of `AudioHandler`:

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

import '../notifiers/play_button_notifier.dart';
import '../notifiers/progress_notifier.dart';
import '../notifiers/repeat_button_notifier.dart';

Future<AudioHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.my_comp.music_app.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Music app',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

AudioSource AS = AudioSource.uri(
  Uri.parse(
      'link to image'),
  tag: MediaItem(
    id: "1000000",
    title: "Song Name",
    artist: "Author name",
    album: "Album name",
    artUri: Uri.parse(
        "link to source"),
  ),
);

class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with QueueHandler, SeekHandler {
  final _player = AudioPlayer();
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [AS]);

  MyAudioHandler() {
    print("Audio handler inited");
    _loadEmptyPlaylist();
    _notifyAudioHandlerAboutPlaybackEvents();
    _listenForDurationChanges();
    _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges();
    _listenForSequenceStateChanges();
  }

  Future<void> _loadEmptyPlaylist() async {
    try {
      await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    _player.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() async {
    _player.pause();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    _player.stop();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) async {
    false ? _player.seek(_player.position) : _player.seek(position);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> customAction(String name, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
    print(name);
    if (name == 'dispose') {
      await _player.dispose();
      super.stop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToNext() async {
    playbackState.add(
      playbackState.value.copyWith(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.stop,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious
        ],
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 3, 2],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int i) async {
    print(i);
  }

  final currentSongTitleNotifier = ValueNotifier<String>('');
  final playlistNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<String>>([]);
  final progressNotifier = ProgressNotifier();
  final repeatButtonNotifier = RepeatButtonNotifier();
  final isFirstSongNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  final playButtonNotifier = PlayButtonNotifier();
  final isLastSongNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  final isShuffleModeEnabledNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  void _notifyAudioHandlerAboutPlaybackEvents() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((PlaybackEvent event) {
      final playing = _player.playing;
      playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
          MediaControl.pause,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
        ],
        /*controls: [
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
          if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.stop,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
        ],*/
        systemActions: const {
          MediaAction.seek,
        },
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [1, 2],
        processingState: const {
          ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
          ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
          ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
          ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
          ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
        }[_player.processingState]!,
        repeatMode: const {
          LoopMode.off: AudioServiceRepeatMode.none,
          LoopMode.one: AudioServiceRepeatMode.one,
          LoopMode.all: AudioServiceRepeatMode.all,
        }[_player.loopMode]!,
        shuffleMode: (_player.shuffleModeEnabled)
            ? AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
            : AudioServiceShuffleMode.none,
        playing: playing,
        updatePosition: _player.position,
        bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
        speed: _player.speed,
        queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
      ));
    });
  }

  void _listenForDurationChanges() {
    _player.durationStream.listen((duration) {
      var index = _player.currentIndex;
      final newQueue = queue.value;
      if (index == null || newQueue.isEmpty) return;
      if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
        index = _player.shuffleIndices!.indexOf(index);
      }
      final oldMediaItem = newQueue[index];
      final newMediaItem = oldMediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
      newQueue[index] = newMediaItem;
      queue.add(newQueue);
      mediaItem.add(newMediaItem);
    });
  }

  void _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges() {
    _player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      final playlist = queue.value;
      if (index == null || playlist.isEmpty) return;
      if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
        index = _player.shuffleIndices!.indexOf(index);
      }
      mediaItem.add(playlist[index]);
    });
  }

  void _listenForSequenceStateChanges() {
    _player.sequenceStateStream.listen((SequenceState? sequenceState) {
      final sequence = sequenceState?.effectiveSequence;
      if (sequence == null || sequence.isEmpty) return;
      final items = sequence.map((source) => source.tag as MediaItem);
      queue.add(items.toList());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like it might just be the native behaviour of Android. audio_service just passes on your parameters to native Android, and then whatever happens will be whatever Android does.